# How to set host and port in full java without dmcl.ini

Tags: java, documentum, dfc

Using Documentum DFC, I would like to set up a docbase connection without using a dmcl.ini.

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject docbroker data into the DFC with Java like this :

```
IDfClient client = new DfClient()
IDfTypedObject config = client.getClientConfig();
config.setString("primary_host", <docbroker adress>);
config.setInt("primary_port", <docbroker port>);

IDfSessionManager manager = client.newSessionManager();
//use manager like usual
```